# How to incorporate date range in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement running in MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [dbo].[QueueAuditTrail] with(nolock)
WHERE
    (queueenddatetime >= '2017-03-17 14:00:00.000' 
     AND queueenddatetime < '2017-03-17 16:36:00.000') 
    AND queuetype = 7
GROUP BY
    queuetype
HAVING
    COUNT(queuetype) < 100000;
```

The `queueenddatetime` column is a UTC formatted timestamp. This SQL statement works for the given time range; however, I would like to configure the `WHERE` statement to reflect a timeframe that falls between "greater than or equal to current UTC time minus 20 minutes" and "less than current UTC time" (using the "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.xxx") format. How can this be done?

Comment: What dbms are you using? MySQL, Oracle...?

Comment: I don't understand the need for the ```group by``` and ```having``` clause in this query.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Had a blank moment there. I updated my question to include the use of MS SQL Server. I also wanted to acknowledge Anand's comment; I don't need `group by` in the SQL...not exactly sure what I was thinking when I did that! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like sql-server to me.

using [**`dateadd()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [**`sysutcdatetime()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx)

```
select count(*)
from [dbo].[QueueAuditTrail] with(nolock)
where queueenddatetime >= dateadd(minute,-20,sysutcdatetime())
  and queueenddatetime <  sysutcdatetime()
  and queuetype = 7
group by queuetype
having count(queuetype) < 100000
;
```

Comment: Those two parameters are exactly what I needed. Thanks for your input!